# mutiple barplots based on month column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I need 12 plots (`fig, axes = plt.subplots(4,3)`)
and in each I need a barplot where x-axis is `Airline` and y-axis is their counts plotted for each month.

i.e For month 1 --> `x-axis='Airline'` and `y-axis='counts'` and also appreciate if each bar is of different color.

Similarly I need such plots for each month (12 plots).

```
                     Airline    counts
Month       
1                  Jet Airways   430
1                  Air France    197
1                  Emirates      184
2                  Jet Airways   674
2                  Air France    513
2                  Emirates      369
3                  Jet Airways   153
3                  Air France     76
4                  Emirates       63
....               .....         ....
```

I've tried something like,

```
df.groupby(df.index)['Airline'].plot(kind='bar')
```

below plot only contains for 7 months.

[image]

But this only returns a single plot with all values fitted in it which is not my expected output.

Comment: I'm not sure what output you are looking for, but maybe it would be similar to my post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54717883/how-to-plot-this-this-graph/54717919#54717919? In that post I also include several other links to examples for plotting multiple bars

Comment: @Reedinationer I've updated the question with more info. I don't have an example output to show because I didn't got the desired output so I've explained it.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post the data you are using?

Comment: @Reedinationer Yes. Also appreciate if each bar is of different color rather than single color. I'm sorry I'm not allowed to share the data. You could just try with above few sample points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was working on my own generated data set, so it could not be perfect. However, it also should work on your data.

I was working on data generated by something like this:

```
#import all needed libraries 
airline_names = ['BRITISH AIRWAYS PLC','VIRGIN ATLANTIC AIRWAYS LTD','BRITANNIA AIRWAYS AND THOMSONFLY','BRITISH AIRWAYS (EURO OPS) LGW','MONARCH AIRLINES','AIR EUROPE','FIRST CHOICE AIRWAYS LTD','CALEDONIAN AIRWAYS','BMI BRITISH MIDLAND','KLM UK LTD','ANGLO CARGO','MY TRAVEL AIRWAYS UK','LEISURE INTERNATIONAL','EXCALIBUR AIRWAYS','HEAVYLIFT','GB AIRWAYS LTD','NOVAIR INTERNATIONAL','BERLIN EUROPEAN UK','HUNTING CARGO AIRLINES LTD','TRADEWINDS AIRWAYS','LOGANAIR','DUO AIRWAYS LTD','BRITISH WORLD AIRLINES LTD','RYANAIR-EUROPE','BRITISH AIRWAYS CITIEXPRESS LTD','AIR FOYLE'] 
months = np.random.choice(range(1,13), size=40, replace=True)
counts = np.random.choice(range(200,800), size=40, replace=True)
airlines = np.random.choice(airline_names, size=40, replace=True)

df = pd.DataFrame({"Airline":airlines,"month":months,"counts":counts})
```

I assumed that for one month there is one airline, so I didn't sum counts for the month. In my data set could appear the same airlines in one month. So, please have that in mind.

```
grouped = df.groupby('month')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,15))
i=0
import random as rand
#create random rgb colors assigned to airline 
colors = {k: (rand.random(),rand.random(),rand.random()) for k in airline_names}
for month, values in grouped:
    i += 1
    ax = fig.add_subplot(4,3,i)
    colors_list = [colors[airline] for airline in values["Airline"]]
    values.plot.bar("Airline", "counts",ax=ax,color=colors_list,xticks=[],title=month)
    #As a xlabel I printed only 7 chars, otherwise it would be mess
    ax.set_xticklabels(values["Airline"].str[0:7])
plt.show()
```

And the output looks as follow:[image: output]

I hope that it is something you expected.

Answer (score 1):

I was not given your original dataset, but here is how you can plot your stuff :)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make my own data set here
data1 = {
    'Southwest': 30,
    'American': 12
}
data2 = {
    'Southwest': 26,
    'American': 35
}

def plot_my_data(ax, dataset):
    names = list(dataset.keys())
    numbers = list(dataset.values())
    for index in range(len(names)):
        if names[index] == 'Southwest':
            ax.bar(names[index], numbers[index], label='Southwest', color='k')
        else:
            ax.bar(names[index], numbers[index])

fig, axs = plt.subplots(4, 3) #define our subplots

plot_my_data(axs[0, 0], data1) #for each subplot we give it data and an axs. The axs is defined as [row, column]
plot_my_data(axs[0, 1], data2)

plt.show() # show the result
```

This script will run if you copy/paste it. Then you just need to feed it your data sets. You can specify colors based on names like I've shown, and also label them as such (That's why a function to do this is great so you don't have to copy/paste 12 times).

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for:

```
# import matplotlib and seaborn for data visualization.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Load dataframe.
df = pd.DataFrame(...)

# Plot one bar for each airline, grouped by month.
sns.barplot(x="month", y="counts", hue="Airline", data=df)
plt.show()
```

You'll end up with something like this:
[image]

Check out [seaborn's barplot page](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html).