# How to adjust the gap between xtickslabels?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The xtickslabels are too close to each other, I want to add some space between each of them. By the way, I dont want the gap between the first bar and the y coordinates too big.

Therefore, I want to know:
1) how to adjust the gap between xtickslabels?
2) how to adjust the gap between the first bar and the y-coordinate?

y_order=[123,123,12,12,124,12]
labels_order=['a','b','c','d','e','f']

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=fig_size)
axes =fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
axes.bar(np.arange(len(y_order)), y_order, alpha=.65, color='blue', edgecolor='black', width=1)
axes.tick_params(labelsize=label_size)
axes.set_xticks(np.arange(len(y_order)))
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
axes.set_xticklabels(labels_order)
axes.set_ylabel('Ratio(%)', fontsize=label_size)
axes.grid(axis='y', linestyle='-.')
axes.set_xlabel('(a)', fontsize=label_size)
```

Original output:
[image]

Expect output:
[image: expect]

Comment: Sorry, word typing error, "......I dont want the gap...."

Comment: Please show some code, current output, and desired output. You can (also) specify the `xtick` to be coarser. MATLAB examples can be found in their [help](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html).

Comment: If you are using Python I recommend you check out my post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54717883/how-to-plot-this-this-graph/54717919#54717919 where I believe you would be interested in the `width = 0.1` bit and how it gets passed to the plotting function. You could also check out the links I posted there or just the basic matplotlib documentation at https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html